# How do I get files from github using Juniper Note

Tags: github, wget

''' !pip install -r requirements
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
google-colab 1.0.0 requires ipython==7.34.0, but you have ipython 8.22.2 which is incompatible.
google-colab 1.0.0 requires pandas==1.5.3, but you have pandas 2.2.1 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.15.0 requires tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15, but you have tensorboard 2.16.2 which is incompatible.
torchaudio 2.2.1+cu121 requires torch==2.2.1, but you have torch 2.2.2 which is incompatible.
torchtext 0.17.1 requires torch==2.2.1, but you have torch 2.2.2 which is incompatible.'''